# Convert $^2+6−9=0 $to polar.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polar-coordinates

I need to convert this rectangular equation to polar. I already took a look at some solutions but I have a problem understanding this part:

[image]

how was the square root simplified to three?

Comment: Do you mean $x^2+6y-9=0$?

Comment: The square root simplifies to $6$, using the identity $\cos^2 \phi + \sin^2 \phi = 1$.

Comment: It seems like there is a typo and the square root should be 
$$\sqrt{36 \sin^2(\phi) + 36 \cos^2(\phi)} = \sqrt{36} = 6.$$

Answer (score 0):

Let's try the real computation: with $x=r\cos\phi$ and $y=r\sin\phi$, you get
$$
r^2\cos^2\phi+6r\sin\phi-9=0
$$
so that
$$
r=\frac{-6\sin\phi\pm\sqrt{36\sin^2\phi+36\cos^2\phi}}{2\cos^2\phi}
$$
Can you spot the error in the image?

The final result is correct, but there is $\sin^2\phi$ instead of $\cos^2\phi$ under the square root.

Comment: The OP's question is really how the square root simplifies to $\sqrt{36}.$   But it doesn't.

Comment: @B.Goddard A very shocking typo! I couldn't even notice it, because I solved the quadratic without writing it down.

Answer (score 0):

Converting $ x $ and $ y $ into polar coordinates:
$$ x = r\cos(\phi)$$ and $$ y = r\sin(\phi)$$

Making the above substitutions:
$$ x^{2} + 6y - 9 = r^{2}\cos^{2}(\phi) + 6r\sin(\phi) - 9 = 0 $$

To solve for $ r $ using the quadratic formula, let $ a = \cos^{2}(\phi) $, $ b = 6\sin(\phi) $, and $ c = -9 $. As a result,

$$ r = \frac{-b \pm \sqrt{b^{2} - 4ac}}{2a} $$$$= \frac{-6\sin(\phi) \pm \sqrt{36\sin^{2}(\phi) - 4(\cos^{2}(\phi))(-9)}}{2(\cos^{2}(\phi))}$$$$= \frac{-6\sin(\phi) \pm \sqrt{36\sin^{2}(\phi) +36\cos^{2}(\phi)}}{2\cos^{2}(\phi)}$$

The second term inside the radical should be $36\cos^{2}{\phi}$, not $36\sin^{2}{\phi}$.
Thus the radical should be: $$ \sqrt{36\sin^{2}{\phi} + 36\cos^{2}{\phi}} $$